# Cannot retrieve integer value from firebase child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the integer value which i stored in firebase child. When i get it give error to parse string value to Integer. But when i parse the value it throws this error:
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "results"

Here is the code:

```
mref.child("data").child("device_token).child("res").child("results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    int val= Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue());
    Toast.makeText(RestaurantsActivity.this, val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And if i get value like this:

```
mref.child("data").child("device_token).child("res").child("results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String val= dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
    int intVal= Integer.parseInt(val);
    Toast.makeText(RestaurantsActivity.this, intVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Then app crashes and it throw exception:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Please help me to retrieve value in integer or convert string value to integer. Thanks
here is firebase database data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8a8w.jpg)

Comment: What do you see when you try to `Log` the `dataSnapshot.toString()`

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.assigment.saad.assigmentlocation, PID: 20186
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: check if it exist with .exists();  Does it?

Comment: check in log message?

Comment: try to wrap around your statements under onDataChange with 
`if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {}`

Comment: i used this:if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


            String val = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            int intVal = Integer.parseInt(val);
            Toast.makeText(RestaurantsActivity.this, intVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: now app is not crashing but it is not showing the value in Toast

Comment: That is because your dataSnapshot does not exist, there will be no value to get if it doesn't. Make sure you have the right path.

Comment: no my path is correct. It still gives error :(

Comment: I am also trying to convert it using parse and Integer.valueof(res). But it also gives error in that case

Comment: What do you get on mref.child("data").child("device_token).child("res").child("results") , perhaps to debug this it would be better to break the chain, then add breakpoints on each  so you'll know what happens on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  for read data and and change first insert data using class when getting data that time get data into that class like below code..

```
   private void sqlQuery() {
    Query query =mFirebaseDatabase.child("usersDb").child("UserTable").orderByChild("email").equalTo("vikas@gmail.com");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("Value::", issue.getValue(User.class).email);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sdfsdf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

try this method..

```
/**
 * User data change listener
 */
private void addUserChangeListener(String name) {
    // User data change listener
    // below code name  add your database name
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            // Check for null
            if (user == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "User data is changed!" + user.name + ", " + user.email);

            // Display newly updated name and email
            mEtEmail.setText(user.email);

            // clear edit text
            mEtName.setText(user.name);
            mEtPwd.setText(user.pwd);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You mean i have to use SingleValueEventListener and add datasnapshot.exist()?

Comment: No you can also used that addValueEventListener.

Comment: i used datasnpshot.exist(). now the app is not crashing but the value is not showing in toast. toast doesnt appears.

Comment: you can change code according your db name and table name.

Comment: i add one more method that try it.

Comment: I am trying to get value in string and then convert it into integer using parse or valueOf(). But it failed. Can you help on this?

Comment: if you try  Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()) this line of code then it not convert into integer because dataSnapshot.getValue() method give one node all data it not string data.

Comment: then how to convert? i want that value in integer because i want to use that value in loop

Comment: i have another async class. Can i get the value from that class to this Activity?

Comment: that's i said get data into one class object and make getter or settter method in that class and after that getting convert value useing like user.getId().

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
            JSONObject parentObject=new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray resultArray=parentObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++) {

               //resultArray              
            }

Comment: This is method from another class. I want to get value of resultArray.. How can i get this value from another Activity class?

Answer (score 0):

try this way to get int value from fierbase

```
mref.child("data").child("device_token").child("res").child("results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   int intVal = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
    Toast.makeText(RestaurantsActivity.this, intVal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: can you add fierbase data   with question

Comment: i have added check plz

Comment: clean and rebuid your project or disable instnt run

Comment: beacuse i am using same funtion to get count from my fierbase

Comment: are you getting value on integer? and are you storing that value in string or integer?

Comment: i am getting in integer  and store in integer

Comment: i am also using exaclty same code but no success :(

Comment: have you set firebase rules for accessing data?

Comment: i am using test rules. I can get values

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    mref.child("data").child("device_token").child("res").child("results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int val = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
            Toast.makeText(RestaurantsActivity.this, val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```